# How do I fix the z-index with an absolute nav bar and a relative image?

Tags: html, css, navigation, position, z-index

so, I'm trying to have an absolutely positioned navigation bar, stacked on top of an image, I would like it set so that the navigation changes to a solid color background on scroll, but the issue I'm running into is with the z-index. The navigation just refuses to stack over the image, which is positioned relative. The two items are also siblings in the html, so there shouldn't be an issue with the parent overshadowing the child element.

```css
nav {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

#hero-image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav id="top-nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item">Home</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Course Catalog</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Products &amp; Services</li>
    <li class="nav-item">About</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<img id="hero-image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/spacecatind/image/upload/v1568288870/The%20Line%2C%20LLC/tower-sunset_qtqa0q.jpg"></img>
```

Comment: IMG is a member of *Void elements* (like `<input>` etc...) and does not have a closing `</img>` tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this to your nav css

```
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
```

The reason it was not working was because, you were making the inner `li` items `position:absolute`

Instead of doing this, make the parent nav `position:absolute`

```css
nav {
  text-align: right;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

nav ul li {
  
}

nav li {
  display: inline;
  width: 100%;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 5px;
}

#hero-image {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<nav id="top-nav">
  <ul class="nav-list">
    <li class="nav-item">Home</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Course Catalog</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Products &amp; Services</li>
    <li class="nav-item">About</li>
    <li class="nav-item">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</nav>

<img id="hero-image" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/spacecatind/image/upload/v1568288870/The%20Line%2C%20LLC/tower-sunset_qtqa0q.jpg"></img>
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much. Every time I make a post like this I'm surprised by how simple the answer is.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the image as background and then use the `nav` tag inside a `<div> </div>`, now as you said give it as absolute and then give the position. So that you would get what you expected.